# Ivy URL resolver can't find descriptor

Tags: ivy, descriptor

I have a URL Resolver in my `ivysettings.xml` defined like so:

```
<url name="repo">
    <ivy pattern="http://repo.example.com/repo/[organization]/[module]/
        1.0-SNAPSHOT/[artifact]-[revision]-ivy.xml" />
    <artifact pattern="http://repo.example.com/repo/[organization]/[module]/
        1.0-SNAPSHOT/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>
</url>
```

I have two files in my repository:

> http://repo.example.com/repo/myorg/mymodule/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mymodule-1.0.0-ivy.xml
>   http://repo.example.com/repo/myorg/mymodule/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mymodule-1.0.0.jar

Ivy doesn't seem to be finding my descriptor when I resolve. I tried running with the verbose flag and saw this entry:

> tried [http://repo.example.com/repo/myorg/mymodule/1.0-SNAPSHOT/ivy-[revision]-ivy.xml](http://repo.example.com/repo/myorg/mymodule/1.0-SNAPSHOT/ivy-%5brevision%5d-ivy.xml)

This doesn't match my expectation. Why is it looking for a descriptor with an `ivy-` prefix, instead of what I specified in my resolver? I would have expected the log to say it was looking for [http://repo.example.com/repo/myorg/mymodule/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mymodule-[revision]-ivy.xml](http://repo.example.com/repo/myorg/mymodule/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mymodule-%5brevision%5d-ivy.xml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer [elsewhere on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/688707/111327):

> Ivy first resolves the `<ivy pattern... />`, with the organization, module, and revision given, and with the `[artifact]` hardcoded as "ivy" and `[ext]` hardcoded as "xml".

Looks like Ivy wants to force an `ivy-[revision].xml` naming convention. Trying to get around it with a pattern like `http://repo.example.com/repo/[organization]/[module]/1.0-SNAPSHOT/[module]-[revision]-[artifact].xml` throws a `NullPointerException`.